# Is it possible to recover a tab in Spyder

Tags: python, python3

I am new on python, and by mistake I deleted my tab that I was working on. There is a way to recover all the code I wrote? I am using Spyder as the IDE.

Comment: Python is a programming language. You're probably talking about some IDE or REPL used to code in Python. Which one is it?

Comment: You can program in Python using a zillion programs. The key thing is, which program (IDE) are you using?

Comment: I am sorry that i dont know what it is IDE.. Is it the python version I works with?If yes so the version is spyder(python 3.8).. thank you !

Comment: @ROEI FYI, [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) is the Integrated Development Environment (IDE) you're using. You can use it with a number of versions of Python, not just Python 3.8 (i.e. Spyder isn't a version of Python). You may wish to consider [edit]ing your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

if you were using the IDLE and hadn't saved the file, then I think no, as you have to save your files always or else there is no way to recover them. If you were using the interactive shell, then definitely no, because the interactive shell runs the commands when you press enter, without storing them. If you were using Spyder, this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736231/how-to-recover-unsaved-file-in-spyder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).